# I have a Javascript function but i want it to wait before it continues to the next line of it. How can I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, wait

I have a Javascript function but i want it to wait before it continues to the next line of it. How can I do this?
Here is the code I have so far:

```
function option1() {
document.getElementById('uncheck1').src='../checked.png'

//I want the function to wait here for 1 second and continue

document.getElementById('form0').style.display='none'
document.getElementById('form1').style.display='block'
}
```

I know of setTimeout but how can i use it here? Is this possible? I don't particularly want to use jQuery but if it is the only way then ok.

Comment: Your only choice is `setTimeout()`.

Comment: *"I cannot use setTimeout as that will require a new function."* And why would that stop you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout behaviour with blocking code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863022/settimeout-behaviour-with-blocking-code)

Comment: You don't **have** to use `setTimeout`, but you **do** have to use something that will complete asynchronously, and `setTimeout` would be the obvious choice here. You cannot just stop the JavaScript thread. (He said, ignoring `alert` and `confirm` and all the problems they cause...)

Comment: ok so how can i use setTimeout? can you explain. I am quite bad at this...

Comment: He could block for 1 second, but shouldn't.

Comment: @SankarshMakam: Do your research. :-) It's not like it's hard to find examples of how to use `setTimeout`.

Comment: @squint: ***Shhhhhh!*** ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: LOL, sorry. It's the troublemaker in me.

Comment: what so call a new function inside setTimeout?

Comment: You said you're bad at this. That's not true. But if you're hoping the information will just appear before your eyes, then you're not going to get far. Research is the most important skill you can develop. You'll find your answer and probably learn a few other things along the way.

Comment: True. Thank you for the information. I guess i will have to research more than 10 minutes next time :)

Answer (score 2):

You would move the code you are deferring into your setTimeout function like so:

```
function option1() {
  document.getElementById('uncheck1').src='../checked.png'

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('form0').style.display='none'
    document.getElementById('form1').style.display='block'
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. But take to heart what others are saying. A bit of research on setTimeout() would be very helpful in developing your skills.

Comment: This is very important for you to learn. Javascript is getting more and more asynchronous. It's important you fully understand asynchronous functional programming if you intend to keep working with js.