# setTimeout not calling callback to interrupt while loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a chess program that searches moves using a recursive alphaBeta algorithm (and some layers on top of that). I want to stop searching after 10 seconds (but I try with 1 second while making it work), so I use setTimeout to set a global flag.

```
  let timeOut = false;
  let i = 0;

  setTimeout(() => {
    timeOut = true;
    console.log('timeout');
    console.log('timeout');
    console.log('timeout');
    console.log('timeout');
  }, 1000);

  while (i < 1000 && timeOut === false) {
    score = mtdf(pos, i, score)
    console.log('depth:' + i + ', size: ' + tp.size());
    i++;
  }
```

This sure runs in the browser so I know the console.log statements should be printed in the browser but they aren't. The callback isn't called. Help please.

Edit: Added timeOut variable initialisation to make it more clear. Also, sorry, forgot to add i initialization (not that these declarations are even relevant to the question, since the problem is that setTimeout callback isn't even being executed...)

Comment: Can you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No, I only see all the other stuff I console.log, so I know console.log works. Like `depth:1, size: 21`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` will run the function you pass to it:

- After the specified time has passed
- After the minimum time for a timeout has passed
- When the event loop isn't busy doing something else

… whichever is the **latest**.

You can't use a timeout to interrupt your `while` loop. The JavaScript engine is too busy running the `while` loop to check to see if there are any functions waiting to run on the timeout queue.

Your function will be called after the loop has finished when the JS engine is no longer busy.

---

Don't try to interrupt your loop from the outside.

Before you enter the `while` loop, record the current time.

Each time you go around the loop, compare the current time with the recorded time.

If the difference is greater than the period you want to allow the loop to run from, exit the loop

Comment: This is correct I think. This question confirms it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863022/settimeout-behaviour-with-blocking-code

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single threaded meaning that execution of "asynchronous" statements like setTimeout, setInterval, and XMLHttpRequest get queued on a single thread. If something blocks the thread (like your heavy while() loop) async statements get delayed.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051209/how-does-setinterval-and-settimeout-work) for more elaborate answer

To make your code work, I suggest looking at the timestamp

```
var t0 = new Date().getTime(), t1 = t0;
while(true)
{
    // do stuff here
    t1 = new Date().getTime();
    if (t1 % 100 === 0) console.log(t1); // [debug ]print something every 100ms
    if (t1 - t0 > 1000) break; // kill the loop after one second

}
```

Answer (score -1):

`setTimeout` is `asynchronous` meaning the program won't wait for the `setTimeout` to finish and the code will continue executing.

You need to use [`Promise`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) to wait for the `setTimout` to finish so your code will behave properly.

Also, the problem of your code also lies in the variable declarations, you didn't declare the `i` and `timeOut` variables.

```js
let timeOut = false;

new Promise((resolve) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    timeOut = true;
    console.log('timeout');
    console.log('timeout');
    console.log('timeout');
    console.log('timeout');
    resolve();
  }, 1000);

}).then(() => {

  let i = 0;
  while (i < 1000 && timeOut === false) {
    score = mtdf(pos, i, score)
    console.log('depth:' + i + ', size: ' + tp.size());
    i++;
  }

});
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. The OP is trying to stop the while loop from running for more than a second. They aren't trying to delay its start by a second.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. So I already mentioned at the last paragraph that the problem lies in the variables.

Comment: "Yeah, I got that" — So what is that promise stuff all about then.

Comment: because he uses the `timeOut` in his loop while the `timeOut` variable assignment is used inside the `setTimeout`. His code isn't semantically correct. What's the condition `timeOut === false` for when it will always be false at the end? better just remove it from the condition. Unless, there's something he wants to do with the `timeOut` variable inside his loop that we don't know thus the reason why he should wrap it with a promise.

Comment: They want the loop to start. Then they wants the timeout to run, setting `timeOut` to `false`. Then they want the loop to stop because `timeOut` is `false`. That can't happen at all, and delaying the start of the loop until the timeout function has been executed and set `timeOut` to `false` won't achieve it.