# setTimeout call stack issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I learned about call stack in JS and I tried some code on my own, here is the problem:

```
const timestamp = Date.now(); // get current timestamp
setTimeout(() => console.log(Date.now() - timestamp), 2000); // get difference
Array(10000).fill(0).forEach((item, i) => console.log(i ** 3)); // simulating long-running task
```

The problem is after I run my code in browser, its take much more time than 2000 ms to log the difference in console, likely 4000-6000 ms, but I have 2000-2300 ms in my console. I learned, that setTimeout's timer starts after clearing call stack, following this logic, I should get 4000-5000 ms in my console.
The question is why do I get 2000-2300 ms instead of 4000-6000?

Comment: You are saying that fill loop is going to take over 2 seconds to run?

Comment: On my 10 years old MacBook Pro, yes

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether to make this a comment or an answer.  I think this might come down to a console buffer flushing issue.  It may *seem* like the function is taking more than 5 seconds to finish because it is printing so many console lines, but it's actually only taking ~2 seconds, runs the timeout and takes ~6 seconds for you to see the end result of all the consoling.  Try removing the `console.log` from the `forEach` and see if you can still produce this issue.

Instead, of using a variable "long running process" that might not actually be long-running on everone's computers, let's create an example that will definitely block the execution thread for a set duration and see if we get the same result.  Let's also remove the possibility of the console buffer being the issue.

Here is my example written in **node.js**.  I am not quite sure of how we can reliably block the execution thread in the browser for a set duration.  A lot of effort has gone into preventing exactly that due to its impact on user experience.  One idea might be to make a synchronous AJAX call that times out after the browser default.  In any case, using node we can write:

```
const {execSync} = require("child_process");

/**
 * Test stack/setTimeout interactions
 * @param {Number} [t1=5] Duration of setTimeout in seconds
 * @param {Number} [t2=5] System sleep duration in seconds
 */
function test(t1=5, t2=5) {
     // Get time at start
    const start = Date.now();

    // Schedule printing of delta
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Diff: ${Date.now() - start}`;
    }), t1 * 1000);

    // Synchronously sleep for a duration
    execSync(`sleep ${t2}`);
}
```

Here is my output matrix:

```
test(1, 5); // Diff: 5021
test(5, 1); // Diff: 5002
test(3, 3); // Diff: 3018
```

The inner delta calculating function never runs until the whole execution block is finished.  That's why you see the diff as the larger of the 2 arguments (multiplied by 1000).

---

One way to do a cross-platform blocking example (that's even simpler than mine) would be to use a `while` block with a `Date.now()` as is done in this question: [setTimeout behaviour with blocking code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14863022/691711).  In fact, that question might even provide some additional insight on `setTimeout`'s logic with long running processes:

> ```
> console.log('Before wait');
> setTimeout(function () { console.log('Yo!'); }, 1000);
> var start = Date.now();
> while (Date.now() < start + 3000) {}
> console.log('After wait');
> ```

Do bear in mind that you should avoid writing code that blocks the main JavaScript execution thread, **it is always a bad idea**.  If you need to use long-running logic, leverage [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API).