# JQuery Each Multiple Elements

Tags: jquery

I have several elements with class name "hidden" that basically sets display to none. I'm trying to create a function using jquery that when I click on a button every element with that class name should become visible one at a time and preferably with some animation.

I tried the following

```
$('btn1').click(function() {
    $('.hide').each(function(index) {
        $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

This works but everything shows at the same time. Since I would like it one at a time I tried doing the following

```
$('btn1').click(function() {
    $('.hide').each(function(index) {
        setTimeOut(function() {
            $(this).toggle();
        },1500);
    });
});
```

This gives me an error an TypeError 'cannot read property Display.....' I'm guessing it is because I'm inside another function and the $(this) does not reference the element that I want. How can I pass the element to the SetTimeOut function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

CES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temporary variable.

Here's a sample; I fixed a few other typos in the sample code.

```js
$('.btn1').click(function() {
    $('.hide').each(function(index) {
        var e = $(this);
        e.css('--animation-order',"\""+index+"\"");
        e.addClass('show');
    });
});
```

```css
.hide{
  opacity: 0;
}
.hide.show{
  animation-name: animateIn;
  animation-duration: 350ms;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--animation-order) * 200ms + 200ms);
  animation-fill-mode:both;
}
@keyframes animateIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">start</button>

<div class="hide">a</div>
<div class="hide">b</div>
<div class="hide">c</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks. It worked. Is it possible to add animation?? Or with display none/block is not possible to animate?

Comment: @Charlie wouldn't `setTimeout` be troublesome if there are a lot of elements? Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863064/1169686

Comment: using setTimeout is risky because you lose track of the timer and if something else happens that hides the now-visible elements, that old timeout will suddenly pop into existence and show it again. I might suggest a custom css property: https://css-tricks.com/different-approaches-for-creating-a-staggered-animation/

Comment: I updated to use a fancy css animation with custom css property. It won't work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically how `jQuery.animate()` work. Since you affect all the elements in a row they execute the function at the same time.

What you need is basically animation completion callbacks. The only thing I'd be worried is that if there are a lot of elements this could take a while to execute.

You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218152/how-can-i-animate-multiple-elements-sequentially-using-jquery) on jQuery animation usage and also check [animate()'s documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/).

What would ideally solve your problem would be to have an array with all the elements you want to affect and create a recursive function which executes animations for each of these elements until all elements have been animated.